# Select date mysql request

Tags: php, mysql

I have the request below in a php file. I'm trying to get a date in this format: MONTHS-currentMonth-currentYear

```
$sql = "SELECT DAY(ADDDATE(`dateDebutC`, `dureeC`)) AS MONTHS FROM normalW  WHERE id = '$id'";
```

Comment: Why don't you use datetime to format it once you've returned it from Mysql?

Comment: can you give me the code

Comment: when you select as MONTHS, when it comes through in PHP in the result what does it echo at as?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to format the date after returning the values from your sql query, then you can use the PHP `date_format()` function. Assuming you store the months value in a variable, let's call it `$date`:

```
echo date_format($date,'Y-m-d'); // Or whatever format you want to display
```

To add the current month and current year to that string, you can use the `date()` function:

```
$current_month = date(m); // prints current month in numeric format (01-12)
$current_year = date(Y); // prints current year as a 4-digit representation
$new_date = $date . '-' . $current_month . '-' . $current_year;
```

See https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp for a list of all parameters. And as a friendly reminder, please ensure that you are using `mysqli` rather than `mysql`, which is deprecated.

Comment: Excellent, you can accept this answer by clicking on the checkmark just below the voting arrows. :)

Answer (score 0):

To get current month and year you can use **GETDATE** function in sql

```
$sql = "SELECT MONTH(ADDDATE(`dateDebutC`, `dureeC`))AS MONTHS,MONTH(GETDATE()) as curmonth,YEAR(GETDATE()) as curyear FROM normalW  where id = '$id'";
```

Comment: That you can do it in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever this comes through as in result, for example, however you bind it:

```
$date = '2014-04-15 10:10:11';
$buildDate          = new DateTime(strtotime($date));
$dowMonthDayYear    = $buildDate->format('l F j, Y');   

echo dowMonthDayYear // turns as April 15th, 2014
```

You can lookup datetime in php manual for other formats theres tons